# Android: Scaling two canvases simultaneously

Tags: android, canvas, scale, multi-touch

I am creating a multitouch app that relies on an image having multiple "hit boxes" that the user cannot see, but performs an action when touched.

I have created a canvas and bitmap that keeps the hitbox information.  However, panning and scaling my view's canvas in onDraw does not so the same thing to the bitmap that has the hitbox areas.

See below for the specific code.  (hitbox and b are bitmaps, hb is a canvas)  Any help is appreciated.

```
public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    mBackground = this.getBackground();
    mBackground.setBounds(0, 0, mBackground.getIntrinsicWidth(), mBackground.getIntrinsicHeight());
    this.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    // Create our ScaleGestureDetector

    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    hitbox = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.hitbox);

    b = hitbox.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    hb = new Canvas(b);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    super.onDraw(hb);

    canvas.save();
    hb.save();

    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    hb.translate(mPosX, mPosY);

    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    hb.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);

    mBackground.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
    hb.restore();
}
```